# Duplicate task instances created for one process instance in Camunda

Tags: camunda

I have deployed bpmn workflow which is creating duplicate task instances. On my further investigation I noticed the `ACT_HI_ACTINST` table which records sequence of activities regarding the process instance of workflow. What I found is, in b/w `Account Review` stage to `Manager 1` stage, the `exclusiveGateway` and `parallelGateway` records are appeared twice which leads to the creation of duplicate tasks for `Manager 1`. What went wrong with bpmn deployed attached here? I am using Camunda 7.11.0.

[image]

@rob2universe please find the attached xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" id="definitions_aa944ebe-cbcd-4b68-98df-de24c78ae605" targetNamespace="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="4.12.0">
  <process id="weeklyPayments" name="Weekly Payments" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startEvent_0489fe56-21df-4cc0-85f3-86b8ac15f1b1" name="Weekly payments Start">
      <outgoing>sequenceFlow_43dd42e8-47fc-4bb5-8f5d-387db79f3e6c</outgoing>
    </startEvent>
    <userTask id="payrollAccountantReviewTaskId" name="Account review" camunda:assignee="0afc00a7-1689-4003-b99f-116f7d42da17">
      <incoming>sequenceFlow_43dd42e8-47fc-4bb5-8f5d-387db79f3e6c</incoming>
      <incoming>sequenceFlow_dfbc5aab-c51a-41d6-9af6-03a237d29e5f</incoming>
      <outgoing>sequenceFlow_f091e4f1-d246-4a3f-8cc5-d0811a4651eb</outgoing>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow_43dd42e8-47fc-4bb5-8f5d-387db79f3e6c" sourceRef="startEvent_0489fe56-21df-4cc0-85f3-86b8ac15f1b1" targetRef="payrollAccountantReviewTaskId" />
    <exclusiveGateway id="exclusiveGatewayBeforeApproval">
      <incoming>sequenceFlow_f091e4f1-d246-4a3f-8cc5-d0811a4651eb</incoming>
      <outgoing>sequenceFlow_c713a794-a008-416a-811c-58be2650afaa</outgoing>
    </exclusiveGateway>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow_f091e4f1-d246-4a3f-8cc5-d0811a4651eb" sourceRef="payrollAccountantReviewTaskId" targetRef="exclusiveGatewayBeforeApproval" />
    <parallelGateway id="standardWorkflow_1parallelGateLevel1">
      <incoming>sequenceFlow_c713a794-a008-416a-811c-58be2650afaa</incoming>
      <outgoing>sequenceFlow_1b2992c2-6bbf-43a5-bd15-9bdd2a91c1de</outgoing>
    </parallelGateway>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow_c713a794-a008-416a-811c-58be2650afaa" sourceRef="exclusiveGatewayBeforeApproval" targetRef="standardWorkflow_1parallelGateLevel1" />
    <userTask id="userTask_8cd0a009-7d4c-4857-bcce-b0a358be9c39" name="Manager 1" camunda:assignee="165f2d43-a133-4433-8c24-219ec599a377">
      <incoming>sequenceFlow_1b2992c2-6bbf-43a5-bd15-9bdd2a91c1de</incoming>
      <outgoing>sequenceFlow_d578879e-ce63-4a37-96ed-ea357c63a2d0</outgoing>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow_1b2992c2-6bbf-43a5-bd15-9bdd2a91c1de" sourceRef="standardWorkflow_1parallelGateLevel1" targetRef="userTask_8cd0a009-7d4c-4857-bcce-b0a358be9c39" />
    <exclusiveGateway id="standardWorkflow_1exclusiveGateApprovalLevel1" gatewayDirection="Diverging">
      <incoming>sequenceFlow_d578879e-ce63-4a37-96ed-ea357c63a2d0</incoming>
      <outgoing>sequenceFlow_dfbc5aab-c51a-41d6-9af6-03a237d29e5f</outgoing>
      <outgoing>Flow_0dhem2c</outgoing>
    </exclusiveGateway>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow_d578879e-ce63-4a37-96ed-ea357c63a2d0" sourceRef="userTask_8cd0a009-7d4c-4857-bcce-b0a358be9c39" targetRef="standardWorkflow_1exclusiveGateApprovalLevel1" />
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow_dfbc5aab-c51a-41d6-9af6-03a237d29e5f" sourceRef="standardWorkflow_1exclusiveGateApprovalLevel1" targetRef="payrollAccountantReviewTaskId">
      <conditionExpression id="conditionExpression_a0828e4f-68ba-4c1c-ab91-fe454ccd22cf">#{not approved}</conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endEvent_1215456f-e1ed-4be6-bd75-e3eb7dba1a1b" name="Weekly payments Approved">
      <incoming>Flow_0dhem2c</incoming>
    </endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="Flow_0dhem2c" sourceRef="standardWorkflow_1exclusiveGateApprovalLevel1" targetRef="endEvent_1215456f-e1ed-4be6-bd75-e3eb7dba1a1b" />
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_9b401e85-e737-4fc3-879a-23f2a5c74904">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_3ac9827c-4875-42bb-ac8a-2e42f790c559" bpmnElement="weeklyPayments">
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_c7c043df-75ce-46f3-99b0-c60fecb44739" bpmnElement="sequenceFlow_dfbc5aab-c51a-41d6-9af6-03a237d29e5f">
        <di:waypoint x="831" y="143" />
        <di:waypoint x="831" y="270" />
        <di:waypoint x="406" y="270" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="1343" y="243" width="34" height="14" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_96d0e27e-e6d5-4789-8594-3513310041dd" bpmnElement="sequenceFlow_d578879e-ce63-4a37-96ed-ea357c63a2d0">
        <di:waypoint x="756" y="118" />
        <di:waypoint x="806" y="118" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_38784eaf-da72-4325-b7d2-0cfd683f26c0" bpmnElement="sequenceFlow_1b2992c2-6bbf-43a5-bd15-9bdd2a91c1de">
        <di:waypoint x="606" y="118" />
        <di:waypoint x="656" y="118" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_404bebd5-39e7-4b0f-b99f-bedaf6e45cfc" bpmnElement="sequenceFlow_c713a794-a008-416a-811c-58be2650afaa">
        <di:waypoint x="506" y="118" />
        <di:waypoint x="556" y="118" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_13585ad2-8ee9-4257-a654-3208c36ac7eb" bpmnElement="sequenceFlow_f091e4f1-d246-4a3f-8cc5-d0811a4651eb">
        <di:waypoint x="356" y="230" />
        <di:waypoint x="356" y="118" />
        <di:waypoint x="456" y="118" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_39143a53-8255-453b-a745-34fe234aa4e1" bpmnElement="sequenceFlow_43dd42e8-47fc-4bb5-8f5d-387db79f3e6c">
        <di:waypoint x="208" y="270" />
        <di:waypoint x="306" y="270" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_0dhem2c_di" bpmnElement="Flow_0dhem2c">
        <di:waypoint x="856" y="118" />
        <di:waypoint x="932" y="118" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_2420f9d5-d6c9-4367-b4eb-5da788186a33" bpmnElement="startEvent_0489fe56-21df-4cc0-85f3-86b8ac15f1b1">
        <dc:Bounds x="172" y="252" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="150" y="288" width="88" height="27" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_d5ebb429-87d2-4cf4-b98d-c1b1c1f22402" bpmnElement="payrollAccountantReviewTaskId">
        <dc:Bounds x="306" y="230" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_877ee2fd-54e0-4c3d-8710-5b50d2e2b696" bpmnElement="exclusiveGatewayBeforeApproval" isMarkerVisible="true">
        <dc:Bounds x="456" y="93" width="50" height="50" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_02a3cde9-8508-4420-9597-ba7cf5977ed9" bpmnElement="standardWorkflow_1parallelGateLevel1">
        <dc:Bounds x="556" y="93" width="50" height="50" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_336a138c-1325-4596-a68c-364bf0951aa0" bpmnElement="userTask_8cd0a009-7d4c-4857-bcce-b0a358be9c39">
        <dc:Bounds x="656" y="78" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_11ddb890-d80a-46ec-9c67-beaaf3b5723f" bpmnElement="standardWorkflow_1exclusiveGateApprovalLevel1" isMarkerVisible="true">
        <dc:Bounds x="806" y="93" width="50" height="50" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_bca69cf4-b5e9-40a5-8271-92ff9d0c4ec0" bpmnElement="endEvent_1215456f-e1ed-4be6-bd75-e3eb7dba1a1b">
        <dc:Bounds x="932" y="100" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="906" y="156" width="88" height="27" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the Manager 1 task on the diagram. Do you now see two sequence flows from the parallel gateway to the user task?

(if this is not the root cause, can you include the modle xml in your post?)

Comment: Hi @rob2universe, thank you for you reply . I have updated my post with xml which you asked for. Kindly help me out.

Comment: There should be no parallel execution in this model. Are the two tasks surely part of the same process instance? Are you running exactly this model (if yes, remove parallel gateway. If no, is it the same behavior also with this simplified version?)